# All elements of same name, added dynamically, with on click handler all fire when referred by class name but different data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I add an element to the dom using jquery, with an onclick handler with a class=“justice” and data-attribute = “1", and then add another element with the same class name, but different data-attribute = “2”, also lets say I gave both elements different values. I should be able to just call $(‘.justice[data-attribute=‘2’]“).val, which would be different than $(‘.justice[data-attribute=‘1’]“).val right?

Comment: Let say what you want.. you already know it... Why this question is asked

Comment: Can you try that again?

Comment: give us a snippet, and clearly define what it is doing that it shouldnt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should. In your example though, you did not use a period when selecting the class.

Also, do not forget the parentheses following the `val` call [per the jQuery spec](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1).

```
$(‘justice[data-attribute=‘1’]“).val
```

VS.

```
$(".justice[data-attribute='1']").val()
```

Comment: This is the right one `$(".justice[data-attribute='1']").val()`

Comment: I wish this was the solution, but it isn't.

Comment: @acampbe222 Are the elements inputs or are they textual elements like spans, divs etc?